# Inheriting an std::container including its boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a class defined this way:

```
template <typename T>
class MyMap
    :public std::map<MyKey, T>
{
    // ...
};
```

This class doesn't add any members, it just wraps the `std::map` and provides some auxiliary functions (for convenience).

Now, my goal is to make this class boost-serialization-compatible. That is, not only I need to support serialization, it also should be compatible with the serialization of the `std::map` with the same template parameters.

How to achieve this? I tried to leave the class as-is (hoping it'll derive the serialization from the base class) - doesn't compile. Tried to add a trivial implementation of `serialize` that calls the base - doesn't compile.

I also tried to add my implementation. It's ok, but it's not compatible with that of `std::map`.

Any ides? Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think `std::map` includes support for serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Read the base classes section in the **[Serialization documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html)**

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<std::map<MyKey, T>>(*this);

    //Serialize your stuff after the base class
}
```

Comment: Tried this as well. The serialization is not compatible. I suspect this is because if the `version`.

Comment: What do u mean by not compatible?

Comment: Serialized by `map` -> can't be deserialized by `MyMap`. Normally fur such a cases one may use `BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(..., boost::serialization::object_serializable)`, but this doesn't work for a template class.

Comment: template class initialization happens after macros are parsed and unwrapped. Just go to the macro definition, copy-paste into your code, and create what you need without the macro.

Comment: Excellent idea. Did this - at least the beast compiles. Now going to see what happens in runtime...

Answer (score 0):

From the section 6.7 of the book [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260):

> There are three different approaches to making containers "STL-able":
>
> 1. The invasive approach:
>
> Instead of invasive and noninvasive sometime the terms intrusive and
>   nonintrusive are used. You simply provide the interface that ah STL
>   container requires. In particular, you need the usual member functions
>   of containers such as begin() and end(). This approach is invasive
>   because it requires that a container be written in a certain way.
>
> 2. The noninvasive approach:
>
> You write or provide special iterators that are used as an interface
>   between the algorithms and special containers. This approach is
>   noninvasive. All it requires is the ability to step through all of the
>   elements of a container, an ability that any container provides in
>   some way.
>
> 3. The wrapper approach
>
> Combining the two previous approaches, you write a wraper class that
>   encapsulates  any data structure with an STL container-like interface.

If you mean to support an additional/different functionality to std::map with the wrapper approach, you should **encapsulate the map** within a wrapper class, and not inherit from std::map.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can force instantiation of the boost::serialization::implementation_level_impl inside your class. (that's what's created by BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION)

In your case, something like this will work:

```
template <typename T>
class MyMap
    :public std::map<MyKey, T>
{
    boost::serialization::implementation_level_impl<MyMap<T>> temp; //Causes template instantiation
};

namespace boost {                                    
    namespace serialization {      
        template <typename T>
        struct implementation_level_impl< const MyMap<T> >                     
        {                                                    
            typedef mpl::integral_c_tag tag;                 
            typedef mpl::int_< boost::serialization::object_serializable > type;                     
            BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(                           
                int,                                         
                value = implementation_level_impl::type::value    
                );                                               
        };                                                   
    }                                                    
}
```